# How can perform a y→λx.yx 'lifting' of a function into a functor?

Tags: c++, c++11, functor, lambda-calculus, idioms

**Edit:** A one-liner summary: Is it possible to create a templated type whose operator() calls an arbitrary function, specified as a template parameter?

---

Consider the (templated) function

```
template <typename T> std::operator-(const T& lhs, const T& rhs)
```

in the standard C++ library, in `<functional>` we [have](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/minus) the following construct (ignoring constexpr and the default void in C++14, and a convenience inheritance of `binary_function`):

```
  template<typename T>
  struct minus {
      T operator()(const T& lhs, const T& rhs) const {
          return operator-(lhs, rhs) 
      };
  };
```

so, the 'functor' (in standard library parlance) `std::minus` is a sort of a "lifting" of the function `operator-`. And we similarly have `std::plus`, `std::multiplies` and so on.

Now, suppose I wanted to achieve this same effect for an arbitrary function. Here's how I would do it with a macro (for the case of a known number of parameters, say 2)

```
#define CONCAT(s1,s2) s1##s2
#define EXPAND_THEN_CONCAT(s1,s2) CONCAT(s1,s2)
#define DEFINE_FUNCTOR(f, ret_type, param1_type, param2_type) \
    struct EXPAND_THEN_CONCAT(f,_functor)  { \
        ret_type operator()(param1_type x, param2_type y) const { \
            return f(x, y)  \
        }; \
    };
```

... but of course I want to do it the C++11 way (or the C++14 way if that helps). How would I do that?

I had the idea of passing f in as a template parameter somehow; but how do I make  operator() have the same signature as f (and with a const marker)? For a fixed signature, I supposed it wouldn't be so difficult, and the code should look like `std::minus` - but in general I can't really see how it would be done.

I had thought about trying something similar to what I would use in a 'lifted invocation' of functions:

```
template<typename F, typename... Parameters>
inline void invoke(const F& f, Parameters... parameters) {
    f(parameters...);
}
```

but, again, that won't cut it - this will get me the execution I like, but not the signature I like; and I need that signature...

Comment: Are you trying to reinvent `std::function`?

Comment: @IgorTandetnik: If I am, then that's great, since then I can stop and just use it instead. But - remember I don't want anything to actually happen at run time, i.e. I don't want to instantiate any `std::function`s.

Comment: Let me be less facetious. Consider the first example [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/function) for the use of `std::function`: An `std::function` is _initialized_, _constructed_ with an actual function, Then you can apply its operator() to some data, getting the result of the application of the initializing actual function on that data. I need for this to happen _without_ the initialization.

Comment: Why, if you don't mind me asking? What's the ultimate goal of the exercise? As stated, this sounds suspiciously like an [XY problem](http://xyproblem.info/)

Comment: @IgorTandetnik: I could tell you, but you seem to be biased in favor of helping me solve X. I want to solve Y since it's interesting on its own, regardless of X. Suppose X is "I want to improve my command of higher-level C++11 mechanism and idioms".

Answer (score 4):

`std::minus` is a *type*. It is a type which has an `operator()` overload that just so happens to call `operator-` on the arguments it is given.

Are you asking if there is a way to create a type which could call any arbitrary function? That would require that you somehow specify the function to call to that type. The only way to provide parameters to a *type* is via template arguments.

And while [non-type template parameters](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/template_parameters) may be function pointers, they wouldn't work like `std::minus`, which calls `operator-` through overload resolution and such. Function pointers point to specific functions, not overload sets.

What you seem to want is to be able to specify an identifier, and get back an object which, when called, will call that identifier exactly as though you had called it directly. This includes overload resolution and the like.

C++ as a language cannot do that. The paper [P0119 (PDF)](http://www.open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/WG21/docs/papers/2015/p0119r0.pdf) is a proposal for adding such a language feature, though it doesn't handle member functions. It's not clear where this went in Kona in 2015, if it was even presented.

The closest you can get is a refinement of your macro via C++14 lambdas:

```
#define CREATE_FUNCTOR(f) \
    [=](auto&& ...args) -> decltype(auto) \
    { \
        return f(std::forward<decltype(args)>(args)...); \
    }
```

The reason to use a lambda here is because, if you use this within a member function, the lambda will be able to capture `this` if `f` happens to be a member function. It will also be considered a friend of the enclosing type.

Of course, this creates a value, not a type.

Comment: "Are you asking if etc. etc.?" Yes, that's what I'm asking. And - the macro you suggest does indeed not give me a type, which is what I want. +1 though.

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you want?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <utility>

template <typename Sig, Sig& f>
struct func_wrapper;

template <typename R, typename... Args, R(&f)(Args...)>
struct func_wrapper<R(Args...), f> {
  template <typename... Ts>
  R operator ()(Ts&&... xs) const {
    return f(std::forward<Ts>(xs)...);
  }  
};

int func(int x) {
  return x;
}

int main() {
  func_wrapper<decltype(func), func> f;
  std::cout << f(1) << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: Can you explain why the first template is necessary?

Comment: @einpoklum This is (partial) [template specialization](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/partial_specialization). This first is the master template. It must exist, or the second will have nothing to specialize.

Comment: Well, this works, up to the overload issue which @NicolBolas described. It's actually particularly annoying, since I actually want the functor and the function to have the same name.